# Getting Python to Read From Bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash program that runs fine, and I'm attaching a Python menu to it. When I run the program I get a message that the file cannot be found.

```
#here is where i tried to format the file to open 3 different ways, 
#all of
#which do not work
 if choice==1:
      file = open('logs/process.id', 'r')
 if choice==2:
      file = open('logs/list.user', 'r')
 if choice==3:
      file = open('logs/executable.file', 'r')
 elif choice==4:
      break
 loop=False
 else:
      raw_input("Not a valid option")
```

In my bash I rename the files to the current date with the same suffix, but from my understanding python should be able to read the first name it was assigned, is that correct?
If you want to see all of the code it is here: [Getting Python to Read Files from Bash in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297427/getting-python-to-read-files-from-bash-in-linux)

But I was told it is to much code for one question so I tried to shorten it down for this one.

Comment: You be using all `elifs` after the first if, no point in checking multiple choices if a prior one evaluates to `True`

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using relative file-pathing.  Where is the python file located relative to the `logs` directory?

Comment: Also `all of` is not valid python code

Comment: both python and bash files in working directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question yet, so I'll have to go with an answer for now.

First of all, it looks like you want to execute a bash script from a python script, but instead you're using the `open` command to read the file.  There are various ways to execute a bash script from python.  Here is a simple option:

```
import os
os.system("bash_script.sh")
```

Note that the bash script needs to be executable for this to work.  If it isn't already, make sure to run `chmod +x bash_script.sh` at the command line.

The other problem that you might be facing is that you might be pointing to the wrong path to find the file.  To help you figure this out, print the directory that you are trying to load and compare it to the actual filepath.

At the command line:

```
ls $PWD/bash_script.sh
```

In your python script:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "bash_script.sh")
```